# SQLite querying for exact matches

Tags: java, android, sql, linux, sqlite

SQLite statement `'abc' LIKE 'ABCd'` will return true. So my question is how to make an `SQLite` query that will return only exact record matches for a particular query.

Comment: I would have to type in all possible permuations of the operation, like 'abc'='aBC' is false and 'aBc'='ABCd' false and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LIKE operator has two modes that can be set by a pragma. The default mode is for LIKE comparisons to be insensitive to differences of case for latin1 characters. Thus, by default, the following expression is true:

```
  'a' LIKE 'A'
```

But if the case_sensitive_like pragma is enabled as follows:

```
  PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON;
```

Then the LIKE operator pays attention to case and the example above would evaluate to false.

Comment: What about when 'abcd' compares with 'abc'? Will it return true?

Answer (score 1):

for exact record match you need to use = sign.

ex : abc = abc.

and if you want all records which contain abc words. You need to write

abc like '%abc%' in your sqllite query.

Comment: How can I adpapt this statement to your method. Can you please provide me an example?    `database.rawQuery("SELECT "
      + DataBaseHelper.VIRTUAL_SYSTEM_COLUMN_PATH + " FROM "
      + DataBaseHelper.VFS_DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE "
      + BaseColumns._ID + " MATCH ?", new String[] { c + "" })`

Comment: DataBaseHelper.VIRTUAL_SYSTEM_COLUMN_PATH + " FROM " + DataBaseHelper.VFS_DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE "your fieldname like '%string you match%' and " + BaseColumns._ID + " MATCH ?", new String[] { c + "" });

Comment: Please check my edited comment. Thank you, The one that I typed first in had some missing parts.

Comment: when using exact match with = operator, if some of the rows have null values, then will this query will work ??